# How to configure Airflow dag to run at specific interval?

Tags: cron, airflow, airflow-scheduler

How to configure the Airflow dag to execute at specified interval?

I'm trying to schedule my jobs to run at every 29 days, If the start date is 2021/11/13 it's going to run at 2021/12/12 and next one would be 2022/1/10.

Is there any way to do this on airflow? Any pointer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It can be configured in *schedule_interval* argument while creating DAG() object.
You can use Cron syntax to set your schedule. In your case, "0 0 */29 * *"

dag = DAG('DAG_NAME', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval="0 0 */29 * *")

Comment: I don't think that one crosses over months, 
Next at 2021-12-30 00:00:00
then at 2022-01-01 00:00:00
then at 2022-01-30 00:00:00
then at 2022-02-01 00:00:00
then at 2022-03-01 00:00:00